# Flex Open Source Calendar / Enhanced DateChoose

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, calendar

I currently use iLog Elixir calendar component, and I am not entirely happy. It is buggy, support sucks and I can't play around with the source.

Does anybody know of a good, well maintain flex library project which has a decent calendar / date chooser component?

Thanks,
Sri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to use and extend the only open source calendar I found: http://code.google.com/p/flexcalendar/

Answer (score 1):

Sri,

You can check out our Calendar Component. http://www.flextras.com/?event=ProductHome&productID=15 .  It is a commercial product, but full source is available if you purchase our unlimited domain edition.  A fully functional developer edition is available; and I guarantee your support requests will not fall into a black hole.

If by open source you actually mean "free"; there isn't a production quality one out there that I'm aware of.  Ely Greenfield created one ( http://www.quietlyscheming.com/blog/components/interactive-calendar/ ) but it is of demo quality.  FlexLib has the Flex Scheduling Framework ( http://code.google.com/p/flexlib/ ) although many complain it is too complicated.

Any questions, feel free to contact me directly at http://www.flextras.com/?event=ContactForm

---

December 2014 update:  The Flextras Components, including our Calendar have been open sourced under the Apache license.  You can get the code from [GitHub](https://github.com/Flextras/FlextrasComponents/) account if you want to build it yourself, or get binary builds (AKA SWCs) from the Flextras web site.

Answer (score 0):

I've played a little bit with the one from http://www.keepcore.com/composants-flex/flex-calendar-component.html, but I did not used it in production.

Comment: this one isn't open source; they have a trial version on offer. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Free & open source Calendar / date picker: 

https://github.com/nidin/as3-date-picker

there's also this one, but isn't free for commercial use https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/exchange/index.cfm?event=extensionDetail&extid=2032022